# Replace leading zeros in timecode string

Tags: c#

The host program I am using produces a string timecode as follows:

```
00:00:01.523
```

How can I replace leading zeros and change it to the following:

```
--:--:-1.523
```

Comment: Have you even tried something ? What is giving you a problem ? Please provide more info and possibly attempted code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Regex.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z(v=vs.110).aspx) method with a [*zero-width negative lookbehind assertion*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx#zerowidth_negative_lookbehind_assertion):

```
string input = "00:00:01.523";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, "(?<![1-9].*)0", "-");
// Output: "--:--:-1.523"
```

The regular expression `(?<![1-9].*)0` has two main parts:

- `(?<![1-9].*)` is a zero-width negative lookbehind assertion. It verifies that the input string does *not* match `[1-9].*` to the left of the current position. (The regular expression `[1-9].*` matches any digit 1–9, followed by an arbitrary string.)
- `0` matches the digit 0.

Putting these two parts together, the regular expression as a whole matches any digit 0 that is *not* preceded by any digit 1–9 — namely, leading zeroes.